# Вызвать метод класса в этом же классе python

Tags: python, ооп

Учу ооп в питон, столкнулся с ошибкой, которую не понимаю. Я хочу вызвать метод класса внутри него самого, но получаю ошибку `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`
Мой код:

```
class Cat:
    def __init__(self,name='Alex'):
        self.name=name

    def prnt(self):
        print(self.name)
    self.prnt()
p1=Cat()
```

Comment: `self.prnt()` у вас не находится ни в каком методе, только в методах есть доступ к `self`. Если нужно чтобы метод prnt вызывался при создании объекта, делайте вызов `self.prnt()` в конце метода `__init__`.

Comment: Что означает "вызвать метод класса внутри него самого"? Когда именно этот метод должен вызываться? В какой момент?

Comment: @Эникейщик мне необходимо что бы при создании экземпляра класса происходили действия описанные в методах.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При создании экземпляра класса выполняется только `__init__()`, поэтому можете добавить туда необходимую инструкцию:

```
def __init__(self, name='Alex'):
    self.name = name
    print(self.name)
```

Если же хочется именно метод класса, то вызвать его в  `__init__()`:

```
class Cat:

    def __init__(self, name = 'Alex'):
        self.name = name
        self.prnt()

    def prnt(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Comment: Про вторую половину ответа не уверен - все работает и если init до объявления метода

Comment: @splash58 да, точно. Мне даже и не пришло в голову проверить. В простом скрипте не работает же.